# how to set suffix for base url in spring boot automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My base url is http://localhost:8090 I want to change the base url of my website to http://localhost:8090/hello

The approaches i have tries is in application.properties
server.servlet.context-path= /hello

but in this solution for every other request i have to send the hello in the url explicitly, what i want is that i want /hello to be appended in the url automatically.

like if i have a homepage.jsp and pdp.jsp
in homepage.jsp i have anchor tag with href="/pdp", so what i want i only click on anchor tag and it should autoomatically redirect me to 
http://localhost:8090/hello/pdp

What currently i am getting as i hit on http://localhost:8090/hello/homepage
my homepage.jsp renders but when i click on [Go to PDP](/pdp).
It redirects me to http://localhost:8090/pdp i want it to redirect me to 
http://localhost:8090/hello/pdp

homepage.jsp

## Welcome to homepage

[Go to PDP](/pdp)

pdp.jsp

## Welcome to PDP

My Controllers are

*HomepageController.java*

```
@Controller
public class HomepageController {

    @GetMapping("/homepage")
    public String homepage() {
        return "homepage";
    }
}
```

*PDPController.java*

```
@Controller
public class PDPController {

    @GetMapping("/pdp")
    public String pdp() {
        return "pdp";
    }
}
```

Comment: What view technology are you using? E.g. if using Thymeleaf, then `href="@{/pdp}"` will automatically prefix the context url, so the page sent to the browser would say `href="/hello/pdp"`. For JSPs, Spring provides a tag library with similar support.

Comment: I am using jsp as view technology, what is the name of the tag library for similar support. Are you talking about JSTL? if yes it is not working with JSTL

Comment: You should learn to do research on your own, it will help you immensely as a programmer. Try a web search for [`Spring tag library`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Spring+tag+library). You'll be amazed at how easy it can be, and how much you can learn that way.

Comment: Done with all those things but not finding anything which can exactly help me out with this issue

Comment: Really? See [spring JSP Tag Library - The **url** tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-tld.html#spring.tld.url)